# Looping sound effects in CocosDension, Cocos 2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

CocosDension's SimpleAudioEngine offers way to loop background music. But only one music file can be played at a time. I need to loop multiple sound files. Is there an easy way to achieve this using CocosDension of Cocos 2d?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the CDSoundSource you can set if you want to loop or not the sound.
Yes define a CDSoundSource for each sound and play independently.

Check the samples in the CocosDenshion folder, specifically FadeToGrey/TheAudioCode class.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the

```
SimpleAudioEngine::playEffect(soundfile, true)
```

This will play the effect in a loop

Comment: Does not exist.
`-(ALuint) playEffect:(NSString*) filePath;` and `-(ALuint) playEffect:(NSString*) filePath pitch:(Float32) pitch pan:(Float32) pan gain:(Float32) gain;` only.